# Inductive step in Proof of Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove by induction:

> $1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + · · · + (2n − 1)^2 =\frac n3 (2n − 1)(2n + 1)$

So first I proved the base case ($n = 1$) which holds true.

Tried doing the Inductive step where $n = n + 1$.

So when substituting I got:
$((n(2n − 1)(2n + 1))/3) + (2n+1)^2$, and then when I referenced another example from my lecture slides the equation becomes

> $((2n − 1)(n(2n + 1)3(2n+1)))/3)$

Why did the $(2n+1)^2$ lose its exponent and why did the $n$ move places from being next to $(2n − 1)$ to $(2n + 1)$?

Then after further simplifying it becomes $((2n − 1)(2n + 1)(n + 3))/3$.
Then what do I do after this?

Comment: Try to take $k, h$ or any other letter other than $n$. It prevents from confusions.

Comment: The highlighted "stuff" is actually $n(2n-1)(2n+1)^2$ provided that you wrote it correctly. And, in general you have,

$$n(2n-1)(2n+1)^2\neq \frac{n}{3}(2n-1)(2n+1)+(2n+1)^2$$

So, either you referenced incorrectly or your lecture slides might be flawed. I hope I didn't make any mistake. Notify me if I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the overview of the inductive step.

$$\begin{align}~S_{n+1}&=S_n+(2n+1)^2\\&=\frac{n}{3}(2n-1)(2n+1)+(2n+1)^2\\&=(2n+1)\left(\frac{n}{3}(2n-1)+(2n+1)\right)\\&=(2n+1)\left(\frac{2n^2+5n+3}{3}\right)\\&=(2n+1)\left(\frac{(2n+3)(n+1)}{3}\right)=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}=\ldots\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand the transition between the 2nd step and the 3rd step. Why does $\frac{n}{3}(2n-1)$ add to $2n+1$?

Comment: @Kingler, What I did is essentially take $(2n+1)$ common from both the terms. Recall the distributive law of multiplication over addition (identity for all $x,y,z$):
 
$$xy+xz=x(y+z)$$